# Writing a linear function as a periodic function

Tags: periodic-functions

I want to write a mathematical expression of this graph
[image]

First thing that I notice is it's actually $f(t) = 6-4t$ with it domains restricted at $[0,2]$. Can I write expression of $x(t)$ as $x(t)=x(t+2)=6-4t$? Or is there any more "right" way to write the expression of $x(t)$?

Thank you

Comment: You can write $x(t) = x(t+2)$, but it being equal to $6-4t$ only works on the domain you listed.

Comment: The notation $\{\,x\,\}$ is sometimes used for the "fractional part" of $x$, that is, the number satisfying $0\le\{\,x\,\}<1$ and $x-\{\,x\,\}$ is an integer. Your function can be expressed simply in terms of $\{\,x\,\}$. Alternatively, it has an expression as an infinite sum $b_0+\sum_1^{\infty}(a_i\sin(\pi x)+b_i\cos(\pi x))$ for some constants $a_i,b_i$.

Comment: It can be written as a sum of sinusoids.  may be this will help you: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math1132s10/sawtooth.html#:~:text=Fairly%20general%2C%20even%20discontinuous%2C%20periodic,3x)%20%2B%20....&text=sin(x)%20%2D%201%E2%81%84,(6x)%20%2B%20...

Comment: @Moti an *infinite* sum of sinusoids.

Comment: @Gerry yes. This is one example how to use a family of periodic functions to depict a certain periodic function. The accuracy of the final function requirement will set the "number" of the periodic functions required.

Comment: So, Airlangga, have you followed up on any of the ideas in these comments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yep! This problem has 2 questions. The first one is asking the mathematical expression of $x(t)$ and the other one is asking to express $x(t)$ using Fourier Series. So, for the first one, I think I'll write it as $x(t)=x(t+4)$. Thank you!

Comment: $x(t)=x(t+4)$ only says the function has period $4$. Lots of functions whose graphs don't look anything like yours satisfy that equation. [and, anyway, your function has period $2$, so $x(t)=x(t+2)$, as you know.]